# Dialog Window Change the Main Window

Tags: wpf, dialog

how to make something like this:(Screen is not from my app)
[image]

When is change the button in dialogBox, it automatically change the Bitmap in MainWindow...
I hope you understand my prob ;d
So how can i make this dialog window ?
Or how can i get access to Mainwindow variables from dialogWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no architecture to support that (like `MVVM`), you can simply use the `Application` object in you dialog code-behind:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
mainWindow.button1.Content = "Dialog rename me";
```

[`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx) object is set on your application execution and is global.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class where you put all information relevant to your item.
All properties uses NotifyPropertyChanged.
One of this property is the Title.
So now in your main window you have a TextBlock bound your object title (it might be within a control that draws the object and write the title above), and when you click on a button  it opens another window. In the constructor( new()) of the second window, you give the drawn object as argument.
 So when you change the title in the second window, it gets updated in the first.